# what does this mean toString function toString() { [native code] }

Tags: android

I need to know what this means and why is it hidden

```
toString    function toString() { [native code] }
```

filename    "Flash32_27_0_0_187.ocx"

Comment: What do you mean by " it hidden", to string is a method that returns a string representation of the object.